# Webpack CSS Loader/ PostCSS Loader Build Error

Tags: css, webpack, sass, postcss

I have set up webpack myself for my reactjs projects and have run into an issue I can't seem to find an answer to. I'm using bootstrap and wanted to expand their style system with the utilities api, but get an unknown word error when trying to build the project.

Here is the error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles.scss)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError

(336:17) Random Quote Machine\src\styles.scss Unknown word

  334 | 
  335 | .fit {
> 336 |   : fit-content !important;
      |                 ^
  337 | }
  338 |
```

My webpack config for css related stuff:

```
  {
        test: /\.(s(a|c)ss|css)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [require("autoprefixer")],
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
```

The changes I made with the utilites api:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "width": (
      values: (
        fit: fit-content,
        max: max-content,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

How I imported the above changes into my styles.scss:

```
@import "./scss/utilities/sizing";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I already tried to remove the postcss loader, but then the css loader throws the same error. Online I can't seem to find any information relating to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Apperantly you also need to supply the property and class values when using map-merge on width with bootstrap, this fixes the issue

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "width": (
      property: width,
      class: w,
      values: (
        fit: fit-content,
        max: max-content,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```